# Set order for posted collection entities

Tags: symfony

I have two entities, the scale and scale elements. These are available in a OneToMany relationship. The scale elements have an attribute called "sorting". In this column, I will save the order.

Also i create a form ScaleType with collection ScaleElements. I can sort the scale elements with jquery sortable and post the sorted elements. After i post the form i will get the scale elements in posted order to save the "sorting" column.

My edit action which handle this issue looks like:

```
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $scale = $em->getRepository('AppMyBundle:Scale')->find($id);

    if (!$scale) {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', $this->get('translator')->trans('not found'));
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('scale_list'));
    }

    // Create an ArrayCollection of the current Scaleitems objects in the database
    $originalScaleElements = new ArrayCollection();

    foreach ($scale->getElements() as $element) {
        $originalScaleElements->add($element);
    }

    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.scale'), $scale);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // remove the relationship between the scale and the elements
        foreach ($originalScaleElements as $element) {
            if (false === $scale->getElements()->contains($element)) {
                $element->setScale(null);
                $em->persist($element);
                $em->remove($element);
            }
        }

        // Get elements
        $scaleElements = $scale->getElements();

        // Init counter
        $counter = 1;

        foreach ($scaleElements as $element) {
            $element->setSorting($itemCounter);
            $element->setScale($scale);
            $em->persist($element);
            $counter++;
        }

            $em->persist($scale);
            $em->flush();

        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', $this->get('translator')->trans('object edited', array()));
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('scale_list'));
    }

    return $this->render('AppMyBundle:Scale:edit.html.twig', array("form" => $form->createView()));
}
```

But the sorting attribute do not change from scale elements. It have the initial state which was set in the add action. In add action exists the same loop which set the sorting attribute for posted scale elements.

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You missed `$em->flush()` after your changes. `$em->persist()` is only for addition new elements. Please read `Symfony` [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) more carefully.

Comment: @andrey-sobkanyuk it exists in my code but i forget to paste this part.

Comment: Have you tried to exchange code blocks with `$em->persist($scale);` and `$em->persist($element);`? Persisting and flushing `$scale` must be before setting association `$element->setScale($scale);`.

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk Yes i change it, the persisting for scale and elements works. But i think the main problem is, i don't get the correct order from "$scale->getElements()", i will get the posted dom order from post request. So i can itereate the elements and reset the order. Or is my approach wrong?

Comment: @andrey-sobkanyuk i can access the elements with $_POST['scale']['elements'] so i can get the order from posted dom tree. But i'm not sure if this is a correct procedure for symfony

Comment: What is `$itemCounter`?

Comment: @andrey-sobkanyuk was a bug , it should mean $counter.

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk Here was the same issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4492